# Sorting x,y,z coordinates into arrays within a defined volume Python/numpy

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy, multidimensional-array

Hi I am fairly new and I hope you can answer my question or help me find a better method!

Say I have a set of x,y,z coordinates that I want to subdivide into arrays containing the points within a certain volume (dV) of the total volume of the x,y,z space.

I have been trying to sort each x,y,z coordinate by the x value first, then subdividing by some dx into a new dimension of the array, then within each of these subdivided dimensions, sorting the y values and redividing by dy, and then the same along the z axis, giving the sorted and subdivided coordinates

I have attempted to create an array to append the coordinate sets to...

```
  def splitter(array1):
    xSortx = np.zeros([10,1,3])
    for j in range(0,10):
        for i in range(len(array1)) :
            if (j * dx) <= array1[i][0] < (j + 1)*dx:
                np.append(xSortx[j],array1[i])
```

everything seemed to be working but the append part, i have heard append in python can be troubling so another method I tried was to create the multidimensional matrix first in order to fill it, but I ran into the problem that I do not know how to create a multidimensional matrix that could have for  example  1 entry in the second dimension but 5 in the next index of the second ex: [[[0,0,0]],[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]].

I would really appreciate any tips or advice, let me know if this is not very clear and I will try to explain it more!

Comment: please show minimal example with the output you get, and desired output. "append doesn't work" is too vague for us to be able to help. If the problem is an error, show the error message.

Comment: on another note, you can use regular nested lists as multidimensional array having the dimension flexibility you want instead of numpy

Comment: Are you trying to subdivide into just 2 categories, the points that are within the volume and those that are outside of it? Do you have geometrical constraints that might make this problem easier (e.g. the volume is a sphere or a rectangular box)?

Comment: Julien,  I am not receiving any errors, rather when printing the final array xSortx, I receive the original array of zeros.

Comment: Oliver, I am trying to divide the entire space into many similar rectangular boxes and then group all of the points within a single box into some accessible array

Comment: Again, please show your full example with desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want:

```
# define your working volume
Vmin = np.array([1,2,3])
Vmax = np.array([4,5,6])
DV = Vmax-Vmin

# define your subdividing unit
d = 0.5
N = np.ceil(DV / d).astype(int) # number of bins in each dimension

def splitter(array):
    result = [[[[] for i in xrange(N[0])] for j in xrange(N[1])] for k in xrange(N[2])]
    for p in array:
        i,j,k = ((p - Vmin ) / d).astype(int) # find the bin coordinates
        result[i][j][k].append(p)
    return result

# test the function
test = Vmin + np.random.rand(20,3) * DV # create 20 random points in the working volume
result = splitter(test)
for i in xrange(N[0]): 
    for j in xrange(N[1]):
        for k in xrange(N[2]):
            print "points in bin:", Vmin + np.array([i,j,k]) * d
            for p in result[i][j][k]:
                print p
```